# Can I apply eager loading when getting images from spatie/laravel-medialibrary?

Tags: laravel

In laravel 9 when I need to get related image of any items with spatie/laravel-medialibrary 10 I do:

```
$Items        = Item->get();

foreach( $Items as $Items ) {
    foreach ($Item->getMedia(config('app.media_app_name')) as $mediaImage) {
        if (File::exists($mediaImage->getPath())) {
            $Item->url       = $mediaImage->getUrl();
        }
    }
}
```

Tracing sql I see lines like :

```
...
SELECT *
FROM `media`
WHERE `media`.`model_id` in (27)     AND `media`.`model_type` = 'App\Models\Item'


SELECT *
FROM `media`
WHERE `media`.`model_id` in (30)     AND `media`.`model_type` = 'App\Models\Item'


SELECT *
FROM `media`
WHERE `media`.`model_id` in (8)     AND `media`.`model_type` = 'App\Models\Item'
...
```

I wonder if there is a way to use eager loading in this case and make it working faster ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary/issues/1047.

Answer (score 5):

An elegant way to meet your needs would be to create a new relation inside your model `Item` class :

```
public function myMediaRelation()
{
    return $this->media()->where('collection_name', config('app.media_app_name'));
}
```

Then, you can simply eager load this relation :

```
$items = Item::with('myMediaRelation')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks!
Could you please explain where condition in your code ?

collection_name - IS field in “media” table and it is equal to config('app.media_app_name').
Have I to add additive conditions on model_type and model_id fields of “media” table ? In which way?

Comment: Or you choose the simple way like `$items->load('media')`.